# Limiting results from find command in a depth-first traversal

Tags: find, sh

I need to write a script that finds all files that match a naming pattern, but when I find a match I do not want to go any further down into any sub-directories. I have no idea when the script is run what depth matches might be found at.

An example might help. If I use `find` like this to find my Subversion directories:

```
find . -name .svn
```

It results in something like:

```
./java/.svn
./java/com/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/dev/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/logging/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/text/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/util/.svn
./resources/.svn
```

But the result I really want this particular example are just the first result and the last result. In other words, once it finds the `.svn` directory inside of the `java` directory, I don't want to search any further under the `java` directory (like the `com` directory in this example). But, I do want the result in the `resources` directory, because it is not under the `java` directory. But, like with the `java` directory, now that I found the `.svn` directory under the `resources` directory, I want to stop searching any further under the `resources` directory.

Basically I want to do a depth-first search for a match, and when I find one, don't go any deeper down that path.

Is there any way to use `find` to do this, or is there another command, or perhaps a combination of commands?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
cat -<<EOS
./java/.svn
./java/com/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/dev/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/logging/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/text/.svn
./java/com/squeakysand/taglib/util/.svn
./resources/.svn
./resources/com/.svn
EOS
} |sed 's@/@ @g' \
  | sort\
  | awk '{if (prev == $2) {prev=$2} else {prev=$2; gsub(" ", "/", $0);print $0}}'

# output
./java/.svn
./resources/.svn
```

Note how this example sed substitutes all '/' chars with spaces and at the end puts them back with the `gsub(..)`. As it possible there are spaces in paths, you'll probably want to use a different char for substitution, but just about any char is legal unix filename, so if you have an completely wide open environment, then you'll have to look at your output to ensure it makes sense.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine `find` tests with `-prune`. If I'm correct, `find` does not have the test you need builtin. Consider the following `bash` script, `testprefix.sh`: (Uses bashisms, does not work with `sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Test if "$2" is a prefix of "$1"

test x"${1:0:${#2}}" = x"$2"
```

With this script, you can call find like this:

<strike>find . -name .svn ( -exec ./testprefix.sh {} ./java/com/ \; -prune ) -print</strike>

**EDIT**

```
find . -name .svn \( -exec ./testprefix.sh {} ./java/com \; -prune \) -or -print
```

(Or replace `-print` with whatever action you want to take on good files)

The parentheses `\(` and  `\)` are unnecessary in this case, but make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [find's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) has an example for almost exactly what you need, it's just extended to `.git` and `CVS` sub-directories. Copying & pasting here with minor changes:

```
find . -exec test -d {}/.svn -o -d {}/.git -o -d {}/CVS \; -print -prune
```

> Suppose the following directory structure of projects and their associated SCM administrative directories:

```
./project1/CVS
./gnu/project2/.svn
./gnu/project3/.svn
./gnu/project3/src/.svn
./project4/.git
```

> In this example, -prune prevents unnecessary descent into directories that have already been discovered (for example we do not search project3/src because we already found project3/.svn), but ensures sibling directories (project2 and project3) are found.